# How to make him press enter after typing the text in ExecuteScript?

Tags: vb.net, selenium-chromedriver, execute-script

i want to make him press enter after typing the text

```
ChromeDrv.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_6LbR9')[0].innerText=arguments[0]", Msg)
```

Comment: 'I want to make him....'. Who is him?

Comment: Chrome driver executescript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.